# R lattice control y axis limits

Tags: r, lattice

How do I change the limits of the graph.  Right now I'm plotting V3+V4 ~ V2 on a xyplot in lattice to compare V3 and V4 and the x are dates and V3/V4 ranges from 2000 to 3000. so when I plot it the general shapes looks like

```
_______
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|______|
```

where the y ranges from 2000 to 3000 and it tries to capture as much disparity as possible

but what I'd really like is for the y to range from 0 to 3000 so they look quite similar.  It seems R determines the limits of y itself to zoom in as much as possible but in this case I want a picture of the difference in a larger sense, ie being a few hundred off should not be that drastic graphically.

```
xyplot(V3 + V4 ~V2, data = test,type='o',pch='.', auto.key = list(space='inside',border=T,points=F, lines=T,lwd=5,text=c('one','two',"")),
       ,main = "testing", ylab = "values", xlab = "time",
       strip = strip.custom(strip.names = TRUE, 
                            strip.levels = TRUE),
       par.strip.text = list(cex = 0.75),
       par.settings = list(axis.text=list(cex=1.2), axis.line = list(lwd=2, lty=8),superpose.line = list(col=c("dodgerblue3", "maroon3", "white"),lwd=6  )  ),
       aspect = "iso", lwd=2)
```

so adding 
`scales=list(y=list(at=seq(0,4000,200)))`
only changes the labeling of the y axis not the limits of the axis itself.

Comment: The 'scales' component of arguments to lattice plots would be the usual place to insert values for 'xlim' and 'ylim'. Use a two-element numeric vector just as you would for a base-graphics call. `scales=list(ylim=c(0,8000))`

Comment: @42- , could you go ahead and post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I should have done that 2 years ago. Then I would have  discovered that it was not the correct answer. The `ylim` argument is notn supposed to be given to `scales`. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 4):

The advice in my comment leads to failure and so I did what any good R-noob should do ... read the help page: wherein it shows xlim and ylim as being "first-classs" parameters and not needing to be included in scales-list. (The 'scales' list os for tickmarks and labels.)

```
test <- data.frame( V2 = rnorm(100, 2500, 250), V3 = rnorm(100, 2500, 250), 
                    V4 = rnorm(100, 2500, 250) )

xyplot(V3 + V4 ~V2, data = test,type='o',pch='.', 
        auto.key = list(space='inside',border=T,points=F, lines=T, 
                        lwd=5,text=c('one','two',"")),
        main = "testing", ylab = "values", xlab = "time",
        ylim=c(0, 3000)   )
```